# Is cross validation on a CalibratedClassiferCV sensible?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation, calibration

I wonder whether it is sensible to evaluate the score of a base estimator, say a Random Forest Classifier, using cross validation which is calibrated using cross validation beforehand. Consider the follwoing scenario

```
kfold = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=1, random_state=SEED)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()

calib = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=rfc, method="isotonic", cv=kfold)

scores = cross_validate(
        calib, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold,
        scoring=["accuracy", "recall", "roc_auc"]
    )
```

Or is the cleaner way to fit the calibrated model based on the total training data and evaluate the score using the predictions? For instances,

```
calib.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = calib.predict_proba(X_test)

accuracy_score(y_test, np.round(y_pred[:, 1])))
```